# how to read from array to store in DB

Tags: arrays

i have an array like this:-

```
Array ( 
 [upload_data] => 
         Array ( 
          [file_name] => 67429_133961013479569_306349156_n3.jpg 
          [file_type] => image/jpeg
          [file_path] => D:/AppServ/www/d5n/rashaqa2/uploads/ 
          [full_path] => D:/AppServ/www/d5n/rashaqa2/uploads/67429_133961013479569_306349156_n3.jpg 
          [raw_name] => 67429_133961013479569_306349156_n3 
          [orig_name] => 67429_133961013479569_306349156_n.jpg 
          [client_name] => 67429_133961013479569_306349156_n.jpg 
          [file_ext] => .jpg 
          [file_size] => 34.05 
          [is_image] => 1 
          [image_width] => 720 
          [image_height] => 540 
          [image_type] => jpeg 
          [image_size_str] => width="720" height="540" 
               ) 
       )
```

i need from this array `[file_name]` to save in DB, how can i read this.

Comment: What language? PHP? What database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array name is `arr` you would write

```
arr[upload_data][filename]
```

Comment: -1 this is just not PHP code. also this has been answered with better explanation earlier but the reference wasn't given. This is answer is more like bad fast-food to help the OP pop away from the problem and leaving crap content on the website just from the second day on.